# Cross browser Semibold font issue

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using font **"Signika"** for my web app. The design is provided in  Adobe Illustrator files where they have used the font **"Signika Semibold"**.

**First method:**

I applied `font-family: Signika Semibold` but it works as semi-bold *only on Chrome*. Firefox and IE display the text in normal font weight.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8zck9wc/)

HTML

```
<p class="semi">
  Abcd Efgh
</p>
```

CSS

```
.semi{
  font-family:'Signika Semibold';
  font-size:14px;
}
```

**Second method:**

I applied `font-family: Signika` and gave `font-weight: 500` for semibold. However it appears as **bold** instead of **Semibold** on Chrome.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbj7b1jp/1/)

HTML

```
<p class="weight">
  Abcd Efgh
</p>
```

CSS

```
.weight{
  font-family:'Signika';
  font-weight:500;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

Is there a workaround for fixing this issue?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include a reference to the actual font, but a pretty safe way to make sure which font is actually loaded in each browser is to check the console/network stats for the applied CSS font – it should make clearer which style is applied than the different rendering/fallback engines of each browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Used google fonts with required styles:Normal(400), semi-bold(600), bold(700))

[Link of Google Font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Signika)

Imported the font by including this code in HEAD section of HTML

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:700,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then in CSS,

For Normal

```
font-weight:400;
```

For Semi-bold

```
font-weight:600;
```

For Bold

```
font-weight:700;
```

By using this method, fonts on all browsers look alike.

Answer (score 9):

Some screenshots would be awesome. Fonts do tend to appear heavier in Webkit browsers because they use `sub-pixel antialiasing` for font smoothing. Try setting `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` and it should start looking similar to how it looks in other browsers.

Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth) page for some more details.

There is a caveat to using this though: Generally, you should let the browser handle this. You'll notice that the MDN page mentions this is a non-standard feature.

If you're interested in how these different smoothing techniques produce different outputs, [check this out](http://alienryderflex.com/sub_pixel/).

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. If you have all font-weight normal or sorted and it still appears bolder or there is difference with the stylesheet made with other software, you should check font-smoothing!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your second JSFiddle had:

```
font-weight: 600;
```

Instead of 500. 
Here's your fiddle updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbj7b1jp/1/

Now it's not bold.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But 500 isn't same on all browsers. It is more towards bold on chrome than it is on Firefox and IE. That's the issue.

Comment: @AlekhShah different browsers can have different font smoothing which can lead to subtle visual font weight differences. In other words, it may be the same font-weight on both browsers, but due to how one browser smooths the font compared to the other, it may look bolder in one browser vs. the other.

Answer (score 1):

Semibold usaly is `font-weight:400;`

However You scan specify Your font properties when importing fonts with `@font-face`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Signika;
    src: url(SignikaLight.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Signika;
    src: url(SignikaRegular.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Signika;
    src: url(SignikaSemibold.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Signika;
    src: url(SignikaBold.otf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in CSS. Web browsers have been poor at implementing font weights by the book: they largely cannot find the specific weight version, except bold. The workaround is to include the information in the font family name, even though this is not how things are supposed to work. You can have a look on this link(only runs in IE) and identify the best match of font style from the list is the easy hack to this problem.
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/listfonts.html